# Techniques for improving image quality for OCR using Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, ocr

There are already some posts regarding a similar subject. Yet, each case varies depending on the problem (image) at hand. I'm no expert in image processing, so I've been having a hard time understanding how to translate the other answers to my specific case. Hence, I'd love some help regarding my case.

So, I have the following image below, to which I'm applying OCR (Tesseract) in order to get the text. I'm getting a bunch of wrong words, so I'm trying to improve the image quality somehow.

My question is what sort of techniques can I use in python (with Pillow, or CV2 packages) in order to improve this. The text is already somewhat readable, yet, the OCR still misses some words (obviously). It's not clear to me what kind of transformations would improve readability by the OCR.

[image]

Comment: It's hard to improve the image, so what about applying a spellchecker-like system to the OCR output to try and correct for mis-read letters.

Comment: I guess this is a possibility. Any packages in mind?

Comment: you can't fix this *after* the ocr is done. the ocr itself has to be able to read this picture properly. you need proper AI for this. tesseract will not be able to help here. nor will any "preprocessing".

Comment: I want to improve before using the OCR. I mean, using some image preprocessing, then using the OCR.

Comment: @DaviBarreira for spell checking after you've got the best results you can from image processing & OCR you could try https://github.com/barrust/pyspellchecker

Comment: You can use google vision OCR for those type of image with low resolution. I had check the same image with google api. It can able to extract the text morethan 95% accurate. https://cloud.google.com/vision